# why is my mysql select returning an empty resultset?

Tags: mysql, select

I'm stuck on a MySQL query and don't know what I'm doing wrong (using MySQL 5.0.88).

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT b.some, b.thing, bt.else AS liefdatum_gewuenscht, bt.bar
    FROM btable AS b
        LEFT JOIN bschedule AS bt 
            ON bt.key= b.key
            AND bt.type = b.type
        WHERE 
             b.entry_from IN (1,2,3,4)
        AND b.`status` = "2" 
        AND b.date >= 20120718
        LIMIT 1,10
```

The query should return a single record, but the check for `b.status` causes an empty response, although the record in question has a status of `2` with `2` being a `CHAR`field.

If I comment out the line it returns the correct record, however I would like to know what I'm doing wrong?

Can anyone give me hint?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
After some more testing I think it **b.status** isn't the problem, because if I use any other column and value from the record in question it also return nothing.

E.g. the record will have columns

```
 ==== no =====  written_by ===== 
     1111         john smith
```

so putting in:

```
AND b.no = 1111 OR b.written_by = "john smith"
```

also return an empty resultset.

**EDIT2**
Here is a sample dataset and the query. I left out the LEFT JOIN because it doesn't make any difference:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM bk AS b
WHERE 1
AND b.entry_from IN ( 9900000002985 )
AND b.`status` = "2  "
AND b.bestelldatum >= 20120718
LIMIT 1,10
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `bk` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`entry_from` VARCHAR(13) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`placed_at` VARCHAR(13) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`type` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT 'SF',
`no` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`written_by` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT 'Händler',
`status` VARCHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

hm... how to paste a record... this is the record in question

```
id = 985
entry_from = 9900000002985
placed_at = 9900000003005
type = SF
no = 11
date = 2012-07-19
written_by "Fachhändler"
status = 2
```

Comment: could you give us a sample set of data and schema, so that we can test in a different version of mysql?

Comment: can u check- if data has an extra space before 2! like " 2"?

Comment: @AviC he faces that not just with status field.. so thats not the case

Comment: @nawfal - sample set coming up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `LIMIT 0,10` instead. That should work.

Since it's a CHAR type comparison, you may want to use [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) function or [STRCMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp) function instead of [= operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal).

Comment: thats not true, I can do simple char comparison using normal equal to operator in mysql..

Comment: nope. doesn't work. Also, it seems to be unrelated to the querying for status, because if I try to query for any other field in the table it also returns nothing. See my edit

Comment: While trying to replicate your case myself I realized your "limit 1,10" which will result in an empty set if there is less than 10 matches in your selection. Check that out if you haven't already done it.

Comment: @elcodedocle: THAT'S IT! I must be getting blind.... THANKS. Do you want to make it an answer, so I can check?

Comment: THANKS everybody for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is with your `b.date` field value comparison.
If the data type of `b.date` field is `date` then you should compare like:

```
AND b.date >= '2012-07-18'
```

Otherwise just surround the value in single quotes.

```
AND b.date >= '20120718'
```

Try changing it and see the result.

Comment: good idea, but the date was selecting correctly (thought it was the date, too in the beginning)

Comment: you also had a point. The original query was in Coldfusion and did not parameterize queries. The date entered was reformatted like this: #right(date,4)##mid(date,4,2)##left(date,2)#, which I thought I had to declare as a query-parameter=date (it's a date after all). But instead I need to declare it as a VARCHAR field. Then the query works... So, thanks for the pointer